# Entity column with insertable and updatable false create problem for in memory h2 database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a simple entity create with `INSERTED` and `UPDATED` as columns. Both are marked as `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "INSERTED", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private final Date inserted = new Date();

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "UPDATED", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private final Date updated = new Date();
```

This works fine while running it against `MariaDB` database.

However i am using `H2` database for integration testing of Spring Boot application. And while testing insertions of data to DB. I am receiving following errors

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "INSERTED"; SQL statement:
insert into PROSPECT (PROPERTIES, NAME, STATUS, UUID, MATCHID, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:191) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:152) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3751) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:435) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3221) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2389) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
```

In above exception I am able to see `INSERTED` and `UPDATED` fields are missing and They are marked as `NOT_NULL` in SQL file

H2 settings in test-application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

If `INSERTABLE` and `UPDATABLE` annotation values are removed then everything works just fine. Integration tests do pass.

Is there any restriction at `H2` level with these annotation values?

Comment: There isn't. But you clearlly stated the fields shouldn't be inserted/updated. Hence nothing will be inserted. I suspect you also let Hibernate generate the schema while "integration testing" which produces as invalid schema (kind of). In your real DB you probably have a default value assigned to both fields (or a trigger which does some updates).

Comment: Yes. I am letting hibernate generate the schema. Does adding a h2.sql file with clear DB definition should solve it right?

Comment: Better yet, ditch H2 and use something like testcontainers with a proper database for your tests. That way you are actually writing a useful test, testing against H2 or HSQLDB or even Derby for that matter mike sound like a good idea, but as soon as stuff gets complex things start to fail/breakdown. But pre-defininig the schema should work instead of letting hibernate generate it, but as mentioned you are probably better of with something like TestContainers.

Comment: How you table definition looks like? You need a `DEFAULT` expression for these columns, otherwise database doesn't know what to assign to them and assumes `NULL`.

Comment: In my sql file i have 

INSERTED                    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UPDATED                     TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

In entity i create new Date()

Comment: If your columns really have default expressions with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and this function is not overridden somehow, you can't get error 23502 for them in H2. The built-in `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` expression cannot return `NULL` and default expressions are evaluated before checks for `NOT NULL` columns, if value wasn't specified in the command. It looks like you schema definitions passed to H2 by your application aren't the same as you expect. You can try to execute `SCRIPT NODATA` query in H2 and check how your schema was generated by your application.